# How does django know which registered model to look through when displaying custom headings using list_display?

Tags: django

Take the following example

```
class Adult (models.Model):
  age = models.IntegerField()

class Minor (models.Model):
  age = models.IntegerField()
```

Now I register both of them

```
@admin.register(Adult,Minor)
class AdultAdmin(admin.AdminModel):
  list_display = ('age')
class MinorAdmin(admin.AdminModel):
  list_display = ('age')
```

Now when viewing the entries via the admin page, will the distinction be made according to the class names, or will django go through all models in a specific order to see if that model has the mentioned field. If it's the former, then does that mean that the class name has to be in a specific format - the model name followed by the word 'Admin' ?

Comment: You registered both models to the `AdultAdmin`, and the `MinorAdmin` is not taken into account at all.

Answer (score 0):

Change your admin.py like below.,

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Adult, Minor
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
# Register your models here.

class AdultageAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('age')

class MinorageAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('age')


admin.site.register(Adult, AdultageAdmin)
admin.site.register(Adult, MinorageAdmin)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between the model class and the admin class is explicitely specified when calling the `admin.site.register`, either as a decorator:

```
from .models import YourModel

@admin.site.register(YourModel):
class NameMeHowYouWant(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

or explicitely:

```
from .models import YourModel

class NameMeHowYouWant(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(YourModel, NameMeHowYouWant)
```

Note that as mentionned by Willem Von Onsen, with your current code:

```
@admin.register(Adult,Minor)
class AdultAdmin(admin.AdminModel):
  list_display = ('age')

class MinorAdmin(admin.AdminModel):
  list_display = ('age')
```

You actually registered the same ModelAdmin class (`AdultAdmin`) for both models, and did not register `MinorAdmin` at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
@admin.register(Adult)
class AdultAdmin(admin.AdminModel):
  list_display = ('age')

@admin.register(Minor)
class MinorAdmin(admin.AdminModel):
  list_display = ('age')
```

This solved it for me